# How do I import a template in the Angular.JS directive?

Tags: angularjs, directive

I would like to import the template file declared in the external controller scope in the directive. How can I get the html code in the  Tag?

**JS Example**

```
  app.directive('memberList', function ($compile,$templateCache) {

        ..
        link : function(scope, element){        
         /* 
            I'd like to bring in this section are declared 
            in the html script tag(listMemberTmp). 
         */

       };
       ..
  });
```

**HTML Exmplate.**

```
<div member-list></div>


<script type="text/ng-template" id="listMemberTmp">     
html code

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you transclude?

HTML:

```
<div member-list>
  html code
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.directive('memberList', function ($compile,$templateCache) {
  ..
  transclude: true
  ..
});
```

Ref: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

See section: Creating a Directive that Wraps Other Elements